# How to calculate acceleration from mass, distance and impact force?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, acceleration

Suppose that a body with $m$ mass is dropped from a certain height $L$, i.e. it starts with $v=0$ and travels $L$ distance while linearly accelerating, then hitting the surface with $F_{impact}$ force. No other forces affect the body except for the planet's gravity. How do I then find the gravitational acceleration on the planet's surface?

Comment: I believe there are a few more things we need to know. Does the body come to rest after the collision with the ground? What is the time taken for the collision / to come to rest?

Comment: There's not enough information to find the planets's acceleration constant.